# how to extract VLOOKUP formulas out of an excel cell using exceljs

Tags: node.js, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, exceljs

i am iterating on an excel sheet using excel js library.

```
 worksheet.eachRow((row, rowNumber) => {
               
        // check if row isn't empty
        if (row.values.some((value) => value !== null)) {
          
          // iterate over cells
          row.eachCell((cell) => {
                  
            // check if current cell contains any formula
            if(cell.formula) {
              console.log(`Cell ${cell.address} contains a formula: ${cell.formula}`);
}}})
```

now it can find formulas like `=IF(A1=16,E2,IF(A2=51,E2-H2,0))`

but for cells containing functions like: `VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$ A$2:$C$10,3,FALSE)`

and i saw in the docs that this functions are easily supported but how?